# Can't set referencing outlet for NSTableView

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, nstableview

I'm trying to set the datasource/delegate/referencing outlet for an `NSTableView` to be an external class of my main `.xib`.  For some reason, I can't `Ctrl+Drag` from my Xib to the `.h` file to create the reference.  Here's my code so far:

**table1.h**

```
@interface table1 : NSTableView

@property (strong) NSArray* tableData;

@end
```

**table1.m**

```
- (NSView*)tableView:(NSTableView*)tableView viewForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn row:(NSInteger)row {
    NSTableCellView *cellView = [tableView makeViewWithIdentifier:tableColumn.identifier owner:self];

    [cellView.textField setStringValue:[self.startupTypes objectAtIndex:row]];

    return cellView;
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfRowsInTableView:(NSTableView*)tableView {
    return [self.startupTypes count];
}

- (void)viewDidMoveToWindow {
    self.startupTypes = @[@"Test Data 1", @"Test Data 2"];
}
```

I then opened up my .xib file, set the table class to be table1, and tried to `Ctrl+Drag` from the table to the `.h` file to create the outlet.  But it won't let me create the connection.  I also can't set this file as the data source or the delegate.

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to this:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfRowsInTableView:(NSTableView*)tableView {
    if (tableView == self.table1) {
        return [self.activeList count];
    } else if (tableView == self.table2) {
        return [self.disabledList count];
    }

    return 0;
}
```

First problem is that you declared "`table1`" and "`table2`" as properties but you weren't referring to them properly.

Second problem is that "`isEqual`" compares the contents of the objects, but what you really wanted to do was compare the object addresses themselves (so "`isEqual`" isn't applicable here).

Comment: That makes sense, however still didn't work.  If I NSLog(@"%@", self.table1), it's null.  But it won't let me set a referencing outlet on the xib file for some reason to assign each table to an outlet

Comment: Did you set the custom class on your window? Shouldn't "`WindowOne`" be subclassed from "`NSWindow`"?  NSViewController isn't nearly as useful as UIViewController is under iOS.

Comment: No, the Window is MainWindow.h/.m/.xib and I attach the view to the main window

Comment: Then subclass from "`NSView`" and not from "`NSViewController`" and make certain your "custom class" field for that view is set properly, ***then*** you should be able to connect your outlets to the table views in your xib file.

Comment: When I do that, my MainWindow.m breaks on these lines:

     self.windowOne = [[WindowOne alloc] initWithNibName:@"WindowOne" bundle:nil];
    
    [self.window.contentView addSubview:self.WindowOne.view];
    
         self.WindowOne.view.frame = ((NSView*)self.window.contentView).bounds;

Comment: I edited the initial code, made table1 a subclass of NSTableView and tried linking that way from just one .xib file instead of two.  Still nothing